# Is this possible to write a Quine in ook

Tags: brainfuck, quine

According to this comment from the general question [Is it possible to create a quine in every turing-complete language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568020/is-it-possible-to-create-a-quine-in-every-turing-complete-language#comment2746762_2) it seems like it is said that it's possible.

However I didn't find any Ook! Quine on the internet.

Do you think that it's really possible?

And if yes will we be able to find it?

Comment: [This GitHub repo](https://github.com/mame/quine-relay) has a "relay quine" where each program outputs the source code of a program in the next language, eventually cycling round to the original program. Ook is one of the languages. So surely the answer is yes, it is possible to write a Quine in Ook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wouldn't even be very difficult. You would want to code it in brainfuck and then translate, and the internal representation for each command should be a pair of numbers (probably from 0-2) to represent the punctuation of each half-command. You could borrow much of the structure from Erik Bosman's brainfuck quine.

Updated: here. https://gist.github.com/danielcristofani/1fe53487df1f7afcb5b91c06d95184b2

This is ~40 commands taken directly from Erik Bosman's quine, another ~120 freshly written commands of rather clunky output code to handle Ook!'s verbosity, and then the data segment to represent all that.